# Link 2 Databases on 1 Sql Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-replication, database-administration

How would you link 2 Databases on 1 SQL server? So I would have DatabaseA which would contain all the info, and then DatabaseB would have a link to DatabaseA and have all the same information as DatabaseA. WHenever DatabaseA changes their values, then DatabaseB would automatically change as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)?

Comment: This is called [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) and is well-documented at MSDN.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out Replication!

Comment: Is there another way to do this? I have the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Version and will not allow me to be a Publisher or Distributor for replication.

Comment: What is your goal and why do you need to have two identical databases on one server? If you explain what you want to do with them, you may get alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking databases on a single server is straightforward. You could use the OpenQuery syntax which uses Linked Servers.  In the case of "DatabaseA changes their values, then DatabaseB would automatically change as well", this would require that you configure SQL Server Replication using a transactional replication model with DatabaseA table(s) published to DatabaseB matching tables.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else said...  Replication

But since you're looking for an alternative... put an AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE trigger on every table that replicates any changes on that table to the corresponding table in your second database.

I know that's a ridiculous answer, but hey, it's what you asked for.